# SharePoint Visual workflow email activity add rich text

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, workflow, sharepoint-addin

I need to send an email using Visual studio workflow in a SharePoint hosted app.
Is it possible to send an email with a rich Text in it.

See  example below,

```
<b>Hi UserName<b>,
  An item has successfully been submitted.

Regards,
Support Team
```

Comment: You can try sending as an HTML email. Not tried this before but put these tags and your content in the body: <html><head></head><body>Your content here</body></html>